# "Further develop" in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

In my research, I frequently take an algorithm and improve it in certain ways. In grants, when describing this activity, find myself frequently writing that I will "further develop" a certain method.  Is there a more concise way of saying "further develop?"  Preferably it would be a single verb that has the general meaning of "improve."

Example sentence:

> In this work, we aim to ________ [further develop] diffusion maps as a
>   method for dimensionality reduction.

Comment: Why does **improve** not suffice? **Advance**? **Enhance**? Why did a synonym search for words similar to **improve** not help?

Comment: Is it just improvement you  intend, or  do you plan on extensions or enhancements which provide new capabilities as well?   MIght consider "upgrade."

Comment: ***Refine*** might also be good.

Comment: **Develop** already has this sense. << grow or cause to grow and become more mature, advanced, or elaborate >> [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/develop)]

Comment: **Expand** (or 'expand on', or 'expand upon') is yet another alternative word that would work in many situations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One such word is ***augment***.

> In this work, we aim to ***augment*** diffusion maps as a method for
>   dimensionality reduction.

AHD:

> **[augment](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=augment)**
>   *v.tr.*
>   **1**. To make (something already developed or well under way) greater, as in size, extent, or quantity

Collins:

> **[augment](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/augment)**
>   *verb*
>   To augment something means to make it larger, stronger, or more effective by adding something to it.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers